# Rangeerror (index) : index out of range :index should be less than 30: 30

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I'm using listView builder and it's working fine but giving an ERROR AT THE LAST : Rangeerror (index) : index out of range :index should be less than 30: 30.
The following is my code -

```
child: data != null
                    ? ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white10,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 15,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                    color: Color(0x42000000).withOpacity(.08),
                                    spreadRadius: -10)
                              ]),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Text(data["items"][index]["owner"]
                                    ["display_name"]),
                              ),
                              title: Text(data["items"][index]["title"]),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Answers(
                                            number: index,
                                          )),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })
                    : Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: i can't find any `itemCount` here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `itemCount` property

- Add it to `ListView.builder`

```
itemCount: (data["items"] as List).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your full code of your listview?
For your current code,
Try to use

```
itemCount: data["items"].length
```