# Dart : Index out of range: index should be less than N: N (where N is the size of file in bytes). How to fix this runtime error?

Tags: flutter, dart, uint8t

I am trying to decode some animated webp files in dart but getting the runtime error of 'index out of range and it should be less than N. and N is the size of file in bytes. But images other than [this folder](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android/app/src/main/assets/2) works fine.

**Link of animated webp files I used** https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android/app/src/main/assets/2

**Dart Code:**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main() {
  final image = 'asset/ok.webp';
  File bytes = File(image);
  List<int> list = bytes.readAsBytesSync(); 
  // list.length = 85538 

  Animation anim = decodeWebPAnimation(list)!; 
  // runtime error raised from decodeWebPAnimation()
  
}
```

**Console:**

```console
Exception has occurred.
IndexError (RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 5292: 5292)
```

**Tools versions:**

```bash
Flutter 2.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 097d3313d8 (6 days ago) • 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
Engine • revision a83ed0e5e3
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

PS: I have checked [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68948562/rangeerror-index-index-out-of-range-index-should-be-less-than-30-30) but that is based on the Flutter UI components so The error causing from the component and the answers are related to the UI components only.

Comment: have you tried with another asset image? Otherwise can you post a link to the asset you're trying to decode?

Comment: I have added the link of file in question : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WhatsApp/stickers/main/Android/app/src/main/assets/2/07_OK.webp

Comment: ah sorry, missed that. I tried with another file (ex: https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp ) I get no error so my guess is that there's either something wrong with your file or you uncovered a bug in the library in which case you need to submit it to their authors.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes. I tried wtih your file. It works but it is static. So i tried with another animated webp file and that also working and I checked the length, it is 429422. which is greater than 85538. So the issue is with file. But I wonder why so. I have used same file with React Native, JAVA, etc and no issue encountered. It seems it is  a bug in Dart:Image library or something I missing .

Comment: and Just noticed that the any animated webp file from the whole asset folder is causing the error. asset Folder: https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android/app/src/main/assets/2 while another asset folder which contains static files does not cause the error

Comment: You should report the issue here: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242407/discussion-between-crackerksr-and-manuh68).

Answer (score 2):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'

final image = await rootBundle.load('images/07_OK.webp');
Directory pa = await p.getTemporaryDirectory();
File file = File(pa.path+"/xyz.webp");
await file.writeAsBytes(image.buffer.asUint8List(image.offsetInBytes, image.lengthInBytes));
List<int>  list = await file.readAsBytes();
Animation anim = decodeWebPAnimation(list)!;
```

Maybe, This will solve your problem